# Are there any common law jurisdictions outside the United States which maintain separate Courts of Equity?

Tags: common-law, equity

It is well know that some jurisdictions in the United States, most prominently Delaware, maintain separate equity courts (Courts of Chancery), as formerly existed in England prior to the Judicature Acts.

Are there any non-US common law jurisdictions (including non-sovereign territories, sub-national entities, etc) which today retain separate courts of law and Equity?

Comment: The [Chancery Division still exists](https://www.gov.uk/courts-tribunals/chancery-division-of-the-high-court) in England & Wales, part of the [Business & Property Courts](https://www.gov.uk/courts-tribunals/the-business-and-property-courts). Perhaps "England & Wales" is actually an answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  Definitely not, not least because the ChD can grant all remedies , as can any other division!  I suggest you consult the  lecture give by Lord Burnett CJ on the divisions of the high court (I’ll look for a link) to clarify

Comment: There is a strong distinction between a separate court of equity and a division of a unified court of Judicature given subject matter over matters likely to involve equitable remedies; equally, E&W does not have a system of separate administrative courts like France, even if there is an ‘Administrative Court’ list in the QBD

Comment: The existence of divisions in the HC does not undo the merger created by the Judicature Acts…

Answer (score 2):

The [Supreme Court of New South Wales, Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Court_of_New_South_Wales) (a trial court of general jurisdiction) has a dedicated equity division within it that operates, in practice, like a separate court, even though it is administratively unified with the courts of law in its other divisions.

But this division, while it focuses on cases where the primary dispute arises in equity is not limited exclusively to equity jurisprudence in the manner that the Court of Chancery in England was in the early 18th century. For example, a modern equity division would apply a statute of limitations, which the 18th century Court of Chancery in England did not. This is also true of most or all U.S. courts of equity or courts of chancery. Still, Australia and some U.S. courts at least have administrative divisions within their court systems that are primarily equitable in nature and a derived from the traditional law and equity division in case subject-matter (which is also still alive in almost all U.S. courts as a test of whether there is a right to a jury trial in civil cases).

In my non-exhaustive but not comprehensive search, I was not able to locate any other non-U.S. courts of equity that are still in operation. The U.S. has a number of states with courts of equity, including Delaware and Wyoming.

Comment: Intersting—my understanding is that the NSWSC, being modelled to some extent on the Supreme Court of Judicature (as was), empowers all divisions to grant legal and equitable remedies, whereas a separate equitable court (as in Delaware) is defined by having access only to equitable remedies rather than law. But NSWSC is something I don't know enough about to be 100%

Comment: Unless someone else comes along with a disproving counterexample, I'm very happy to accept your answer (and will do so after the question has been up a bit longer)

Comment: The NSWSC equity division is **not** an equity court. It has access to legal and equitable remedies. It’s an administrative division and deals with cases *primarily* grounded in equity. Just like the construction division deals in cases primarily grounded in construction disputes.

Comment: @DaleM Thank you for confirming—sounds precisely like the Chancery Division of the High Court (both being subject-matter focused divisions of a unified law and equity court); I will suggest an edit to this effect.

Comment: @tex_user_7 the consensus is that law and equity have merged in Australian jurisprudence

Comment: @DaleM Frankly, I would be astonished if they weren't ;)

Comment: My psoposed edit removing the Australian part of this answer appears to have been rejected; given the consensus is that it's misleading, I can't accept unless it's removed

Comment: @user38749 I have revised my answer to provide a more balanced sense of what I think that the existence of modern equity courts means and does not mean.

Comment: Are there lawyers in the relevant U.S. states that dedicate their career and practices specially to “Equity” rather than “Law,” as I gather there used to be in England?

Comment: @Seekinganswers No. There are lawyers with careers in fields that were historically in equity jurisdiction (e.g. corporate law, probate, and divorce), but it would be very rare for any lawyer in the U.S. to characterize their practice as an "equity" practice either as a form of self-identification or as a marketing tool.

Comment: Is there much overlap between the qualifications needed to engage with the different courts (Equity \law)?

Comment: @Seekinganswers The United States has only a single legal profession that encompasses all forms of private lawyers, prosecutors, judges, transactional lawyers, etc. (pretty much the only separate legal professional is patent law which has a separate admissions requirement and doesn't necessarily require a law degree).